# How to separate rows from matrix in matlab based on a value in column?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix which is a 2d array read from a text file. Each row of text file has 3 entries. The 3rd column has values ranging from 1 to 4. And I want to separate the rows based on this value and put them into different matrix. Could you please suggest a way to do it?

Comment: 'ranging from 1 to 4'. Are the values real, or integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an Matrix `M`, as you describe

```
rowsContainingOne   = M( M(:,3)==1, :)
rowsContainingTwo   = M( M(:,3)==2, :)
rowsContainingThree = M( M(:,3)==3, :)
rowsContainingFour  = M( M(:,3)==4, :)
```

To see why this works, look at the results from the following portions of:

```
M(:,3)              %A vector of column three
M(:,3)==1           %A logical array, `true` where column 3 equals one
M( M(:,3)==1, :)    %All columns (indicated by `:`) from rows where the logical array is `true`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `sortrows`.

Pseudo Code:

```
%% Creating a matrix of the type you have mentioned.
A = zeros(10,3);   A(:,1:2) = rand(10,2);    A(:,3)=randi(4,10,1);
%% Use the "sortrows" function to sort all the rows as per the entries in column-3 of A    
B = sortrows(A,3);
```